# How much harder is a proton theoretically speaking than a diamond?

Tags: particle-physics, material-science, density

It's generally said that a diamond is the hardest substance known to man (apparently there are a few materials known to be harder).

However, one ought to expect that a proton or neutron should be harder than diamond. Can we theoretically put quantify how much harder?

Comment: Not sure the question makes practical sense. Measures of hardness for macroscopic objects like samples of diamond depend on pressing the sample with another macroscopic object, which is not something that you can do with a individual nucleon. Nor can you trivially re-phrase the question in terms of, say, stiffness of the equation of state because there is no unique answer for a proton.

Comment: The hardness of materials is a measure of the yield stress, which is related to the chemical bonds in the material. A single proton does not have a yield stress so it doesn't have a hardness.

Comment: I consider both comments above to be answers...

Comment: I think maybe you are comparing with graphene but that thing is made of a single layer of carbon atoms.

Comment: @dmckee: I think it's a matter of theoretical ingenuity. After all we talk about tempratures in the billions but obviously there is no theremoeter than can directly measure such temperatures.

Comment: You can (and people do) measure the temperature of hadronic systems under the right conditions: that isn't mere theory. And you seem to have missed my point about the EOS stiffness (which is the obvious generalization of "hardness"): like so many other things in the world of the small the answer you get would depend on how you probed the system and could easily vary over many orders of magnitude. At a guess I would assume the system to be very hard in the IR limit and soft in the UV limit.

Comment: @dmckee: But this is just as true in the macroscopic world. If I took a hot torch to a steel beam it would cut through it like butter but if I tried the same with a knife, it wouldn't go in at all. So what am I to deduce from this - that steel is soft or hard? Obviously here there is a right answer.

Answer (score 2):

One cannot generalize the concept of hardness to a single proton in a meaningful, or at least unique way.

John Rennie:

> The hardness of materials is a measure of the yield stress, which is related to the chemical bonds in the material. A single proton does not have a yield stress so it doesn't have a hardness.

dmckee:

> Not sure the question makes practical sense. Measures of hardness for macroscopic objects like samples of diamond depend on pressing the sample with another macroscopic object, which is not something that you can do with a individual nucleon. Nor can you trivially re-phrase the question in terms of, say, stiffness of the equation of state because there is no unique answer for a proton.